# VBA Infinite loop - When no value is enetered by the user

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie to VBA and I'm writing a VBA code that will accept user inputs for the serial numbers for the Start and End value and will check if the serial numbers in another sheet fall between the range specified. If it does, then my code will pick the complete record and paste it into another sheet.

Now, the challenging part is that the serial number value isn't consistent and it could be alpha-numeric string with no fixed length. So, I've used StrComp function to check if the value lies in the range specified by the user. The problem is if the user types in a value for start value and end value that doesn't exist in the sheet of serial numbers then it goes on an infinite loop.

For instance, if there is a serial number say 1120 and the user enters 1110(which doesn't exist) for start value and 1200 for end value, the code goes on a infinite loop. Technically, the code should pick the serial number 1120 and return since it does lie in the range 1110 and 1200 eventhough the value 1110 doesn't exist in the sheet.

Here is my code:

```
'Assigining values enterted by user to variables
start = Me.txtStart.Value
finish = Me.txtEnd.Value

'Checking Upper bound Vs Lower bound
If (Len(start) <> 0 And (Len(finish) <> 0)) Then
 If (StrComp(start, finish) > 0) Then
 MsgBox ("Lower Bound cannot be higher than the Upper Bound")
 Exit Sub
 Else
    If Len(tempWorkPriority) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Enter a value for Work Priority")
    Exit Sub
    Else
     If Len(tempDescription) = 0 Then
     MsgBox ("Enter a value for Description")
     Exit Sub
     Else
  Goto Here
     End If
    End If
  End If
Else
result = MsgBox("Please enter values for Upper and Lower bounds")
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Here:
Sheets("Imported e-Facilities Data").Activate
'Number of rows in Raw Data sheet
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop to iterate and pick data that falls within the specified range
    For i = 2 To RowCount
    tempSerial = Range("A" & i).Value
    tempAsset = Range("V" & i).Value
    tempAssignedResource = Range("R" & i).Value
    tempManufacturer = Range("F" & i).Value

    'Condition to check if a Serial Number falls within the range
       If (StrComp(start, tempSerial) <= 0 And StrComp(tempSerial, finish) <= 0) Then
    'Selecting Export Sheet
    Sheets("Data Ready for Import").Select
    'Counting Rows in the Export sheet
    RowCountExport = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & RowCountExport + 1).Value = tempSerial
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: I don't see how it can get into an infinite loop. Which procedure does it happen in?

Comment: I don't see the procedure `FindMatchingValue`? Does it happen there? Can you debug it line by line and checking where is the loop occurring?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See [this page] for tips on how to create a MCVE. The `DataImport` function is not relevant to your question and can be removed, and you've failed to include `FindMatchingValue`, which *is* relevant.

Comment: I've re-editted my code. The expected behavior should be if the user enters a values for start and finish ranges that is not found in the sheet, the script should work and return if any serial number falls within the range. But, that doesn't happen and instead it goes on a infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're using unqualified calls to `Range` so you are relying on the active sheet being set correctly. When you find a serial number which falls within the range, you call `Select` on a different sheet which has the effect of changing the active sheet. The next time round your loop `tempSerial`, `tempAsset` etc will be read from the "Data Ready For Import" sheet which is now active rather than the "Imported e-Facilities Data" sheet which was being used before.

You should qualify your `Range` references instead of relying on the active sheet, `Select` or `Activate`:

```
Set wsInput = Worksheets("Imported e-Facilities Data")

tempSerial = wsInput.Range("A" & i).Value
```

or use `With ... End With` for repeated references to the same object:

```
Set wsInput = Worksheets("Imported e-Facilities Data")

With wsInput
    tempSerial = .Range("A" & i).Value
    tempAsset = .Range("V" & i).Value
    tempAssignedResource = .Range("R" & i).Value
    tempManufacturer = .Range("F" & i).Value
End With
```